# Why this code doens't work??? trying to change image from UIImageView if swiped right or left

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimageview

I'm getting crazy why the code below doesn't work...

I have a simple UIViewController with UIImageView and want to try to change image if the user swiped right or left. I'm new with iphone development;

thanks

```
#import "SummerViewController.h"


@implementation SummerViewController

//@synthesize scroll;
@synthesize imgClothes, images;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)LeftSwiped
{
    NSLog(@"swiped left");
    imgClothes.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:0]];

}

-(void)RightSwiped
{
    NSLog(@"swiped right");
    imgClothes.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:1]];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"], nil];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(LeftSwiped)];

    swipeLeft.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(RightSwiped)];

    swipeRight.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];





    [super viewDidLoad];


}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

.h file:

```
@interface SummerViewController : UIViewController
{
    //IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroll;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imgClothes;
    NSArray *images;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgClothes;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSArray *images;

@end
```

Comment: A few things:  1) be sure to add the swipe gr to the image view, not self view 2) be sure to check @ajay advice for connecting up the UI, 3) please consider my suggestion on your earlier question:  a scroll view already recognizes gestures, and will give you the benefit of an animated slide from one view to the next, this code (once you get it working) will just switch the image instantly.

Comment: I just don't know how to start it with Scroll View, I am going to try here thanks

Comment: for the records, it works if I pass the image name (NSString) and create the UIImage when I need it

Answer (score 1):

1. I can't see where are you initing your `UIImageView *imgClothes`. You should write something like `imgClothes = [[UIImageView alloc] init(...)];`
2. I didn't work with UISwipeGestureRecognizer, but sometimes you should write in your .h file something like this: `@interface SummerViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>`
3. I prefer do my initialization in `initWithNibName`, not in `ViewDidLoad`. But this should not be cause of your problems.

Comment: thanks, 1- I do init it: "images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"], nil];
"  2- I will try it  3- I don't think this is the problem either, even because I am able to assign image manually like: imgClothes.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];

Answer (score 1):

All you code is correct for changing an Image for UIImageView.According to your code snippet I found two scenarios

1.Make sure to add IBOutlet reference from the XIB to the **imgClothes**
2.if "1" point is conformed try to check your **imgClothes** reference added to self.view or not.

Hope above two scenarios will make it out of the issue.Good luck.

Comment: thanks, both scenarios are fine in my app, the problems persists, I'm able to add iamge to my IBOutlet without retrieving from NSArray imgClothes.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget one things

1) `swipeRight.delegate = self;` // assign delegate to swipe object.

If you're using sdk 3.2 or higher, this is dead easy with the UIGestureRecognizer class.Otherwise visit following reference for detect swipe

`https://gist.github.com/791725`

Hope, this will help you..

Comment: it didn't work, I'm wondering about the meaning of .delefate = self... thanks

Comment: @EdwinSoho - delegate = self tells the GR that you want the object "self" to get notified when the recognizer is triggered.  Also, as I mentioned earlier, scrollView handles all the touches for you.